# Apollo GraphQL useQuery react hooks rendering error - why is useContext is undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

anyone get this error in browser console when calling useQuery in Apollo GraphQL...?

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by .......
   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useContext                 useContext
2. useRef                     useRef
3. useState                   useState
4. useContext                 useContext
5. useMemo                    useMemo
6. useCallback                useCallback
7. useSyncExternalStore       useSyncExternalStore
8. undefined                  useContext
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

why is useContext undefined in the first render...? and why did it even re-render?
I am using useQuery in a very standard case...

```
const { data, loading, error, fetchMore } = useQuery(queryDocument, {
    variables: {
      ... 
    },
  });
  if (!data && loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }
  return (data && <Component data={data} />)
```

I thought it might be a problem with the loading state... but removing the loading part entirely didn't change anything...

Comment: Could you please share the full component, not just a part of it?

Comment: please share an [mre]. from what you've posted, I'm guessing you're calling a hook conditionally